# create setup for the project solution in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

So my final query for my payroll application is -

How can I create a setup for payroll application?
All I need to know-

1. How will I add setup project to my existing solution
2. How to add files from solution to setup project and what files to be
   added and in what folder (i.e. there are three folder by default
   application folder,user desktop,user start menu)
3. what will be the resultant file that will serves an exe file for
   payroll application

I have read below tutorial but I am not getting the real solution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2kt85ked%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A simple way to add setup to your project.

**(1)** File -> New Project -> Other Project Types 
   -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer

**(2)** Add a name to your setup project.

**(3)**   Right click Application Folder -> Add -> project output

**(4)** ****Select your respective project's solution "primary output from yours.."****

**(5)** ****Add the respective 3rd party dlls.**** // Never forget this one.

**(6)** Right click setup project in solution explorer and **BUILD** it.

**(7)** Find the respective setup in debug folder(by default)

You will get the `.exe` and `.msi` in the folder.

---

You can change the **configuration** between `Debug` and `Release`,

- Right click the setup project in solution explorer -> Properties.

  You will find a configuration and select the respective one.

Check this [What is the difference between Release and Debug modes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio)

Hope you understand.

Comment: why are third party dlls in my solution ...and why i need to add them..could you please explain..

Comment: @roanjain For some project, you may use third party `dlls`.  **For example:** [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) used for json parsing.  While in-dev you will be referencing it.  Once you bundle it into setup you have to refer it else you application crashes.  Once I've experienced that why I pointed it.

Comment: @roanjain If you used any 3rd party dll, you have to add.  Otherwise not necessary.