# In VS2015 WPF solution, how do I add a start menu item for an exe?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a WinForms application that is packaged with a WPF project. I have set the .exe to "Content" and "AlwaysCopy", and it is included in the installation folder upon install.

I want to include a shortcut in the start menu that will open this EXE app. How do I do that?

Comment: do you have an installer? what type of installer are you using?

Comment: The publish wizard from the Build menu in VS2015

Comment: have you looked at the Project solution | Publish | Options | Manifests | Create desktop shortcuts? or you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303962/visual-studio-deployment-project-create-shortcut-to-deployed-executable)

Comment: You don't do this from the WPF exe. You add a separate project that builds an installer, and have shortcut created at install-time.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string exe = @"c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exe);
            process.StartInfo = info;
            process.Start();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: He just wants to create a shortcut to his exe

Comment: This is how to open another process from C# code. DrDamnit wants to make it so that installing their WPF app adds a shortcut to an included exe to the start menu. You're answering a different question.

Comment: I believe he wants a shortcut in the form (a button) to run the exe.

Comment: He wants to have a new shortcut added to the start menu that launches an exe. Your answer simply launches a process, but doesn't create a shortcut.

Comment: You don't use a shortcut in a form, instead its a button click event or equivalent control click event